# Chaining and Function Composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, chaining, function-composition

Here is a piece of code I am trying to understand:

```
const seq2 = (f1, f2) => {
 return (...args) => {

  return f2( f1( ...args) );
 }
}



const seq = ( f1, ...fRest) =>
 fRest.reduce( seq2, f1 );

const elevator = {
 floor: 5
};

const up = elevator => {
 return {
  floor: elevator.floor + 1
 }
};

const down = elevator => {
 return {
  floor: elevator.floor - 1
 }
};


const move = seq( up, up, down, up);
const newElevator = move( elevator );



console.log( newElevator.floor ) // shows 7
```

this is an example from js functional programming course. And I am trying to figure out if I could simplify seq function so it would look like this

`const seq = ( ...fRest) =>
 fRest.reduce( seq2 );`

????

Is there any specific reason why I have to pass `f1` as a first argument and then pass it further to the reduce method as an `initialValue` ?? When I won't specify the `initialValue` in the reduce method wouldn't it treat the first array element - `accumulator` - as an `initialValue` by default? I will much appreciate if someone could explain to me what is going on in that code :)

Comment: Have you tried it? It's working

Comment: Yes, it is working. But I wonder if the author wrote this function with the `f1` argument for a reason ??

Comment: I don't think there is a particular reason behind it. Maybe he didn't know you can do that. Maybe that's how he likes to use `reduce`. Anyways both are the same.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir reducing without an initial accumulator is invalid

Comment: If this is code you lifted directly from the course material, whomever wrote it should give more descriptive names for parameters/variables.

Comment: @user633183 Reducing without an initial value is valid. It's reducing **an empty array** without an initial value that is invalid.

Comment: I think your solution is even better because it will raise an exception when no arguments are passed to `seq()`, which makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`seq()` would attempt to reduce an empty array without an accumulator, which is an error – not that `f1` fixes this the way the author has it written here.

> `initialValue` – Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the `callback`. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling `reduce()` on an empty array without an initial value is an error – source MDN: [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

A more robust implementation of `seq` will not cause an error when `seq()` is used to build an empty sequence

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const seq2 = (f, g) =>
  (...args) => f (g (...args))

const seq = (...fs) =>
  fs.reduce (seq2, identity)

const up = elevator =>
  ({ floor: elevator.floor + 1 })
  
const down = elevator =>
  ({ floor: elevator.floor - 1 })

console.log
 ( seq (up, up, down, up) ({ floor: 3 }) // { floor: 5 }
 , seq () ({ floor: 3 })                 // { floor: 3 }
 )
```

A simplified version of `seq` that promotes better functional hygiene by disallowing composition of variadic functions

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const seq = (f = identity, ...rest) =>
  f === identity
    ? f
    : x => seq (...rest) (f (x))

const up = elevator =>
  ({ floor: elevator.floor + 1 })
  
const down = elevator =>
  ({ floor: elevator.floor - 1 })

console.log
 ( seq (up, up, down, up) ({ floor: 3 }) // { floor: 5 }
 , seq () ({ floor: 3 })                 // { floor: 3 }
 )
```